# WritableRaster in android

Tags: java, android

I have following piece of code:

```
private static byte[] accessBytes(Bitmap  image)
  // access the data bytes in the image
  {
    WritableRaster raster = image.getRaster();
    DataBufferByte buffer = (DataBufferByte) raster.getDataBuffer();
    return buffer.getData();
  }  // end of accessBytes()
```

I want to convert this code so that it will work in my android application, is there any way I can do that?
I also have the working code in java, can i make a class library of this code and then import in the android? will this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, android supports Java. You can use Java code in an Android event as a library. Try starting at [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/index.html).

Comment: but android does not support the import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
so my WritableRaster class does not work when I try to write it in the android, will this class work if I made a class library and then use it in the android?

Comment: @user2341925 I think that it should to work. Try adding it as jar