# Latest Linking method of Java Library in android

Tags: java, android, jar

Although this questions have been asked here many times but the answers don't really seem to fix the problems I am getting.
I have read that after the updating of ADT to rev 22, the library import have changed somewhat but I have also tried all the things but to no avail.
Now the problem is that I am developing a multi-platform application which will use the "F5 Steganography" to hide a message inside a JPG image captured from the device's camera. Currently my objectives are to make an android application and desktop Java application. I have found the jar file of "F5 Steganography" from [here](https://code.google.com/p/f5-steganography/) I have successfully implemented the library in Java desktop application but the problem is coming in android implementation. I have imported the jar file in the android project by doing these steps:

1. Right-click libs and choose Import --> General --> File System, then Next, Browse in the filesystem to find the library's parent directory, then check the relevant JAR in the right pane
2. Right-click on project, choose Build Path --> Configure Build Path, then click the Libraries tab, then Add JARs., navigate to new JAR in the libs directory and added it.
3. Finally Right-click on project-->Properties -->Java Buid path--> order and export and checked the Android Private libraries and the library which is being linked. See [here](http://img818.imageshack.us/img818/6792/u4p8.jpg).

But the issue still remains that the classes which are present in the external jar file are not being referenced properly in the project.
Log-cat is showing that the class is not being found. Here is the log-cat trace:

```
10-12 16:03:59.492: W/dalvikvm(20569): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/awt/Image;)
10-12 16:03:59.492: W/dalvikvm(20569): Unable to resolve superclass of Ljames/JpegEncoder; (657)
10-12 16:03:59.492: W/dalvikvm(20569): Link of class 'Ljames/JpegEncoder;' failed
10-12 16:03:59.492: E/dalvikvm(20569): Could not find class 'james.JpegEncoder', referenced from method main.Embed.main
10-12 16:03:59.492: W/dalvikvm(20569): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 653 (Ljames/JpegEncoder;) in Lmain/Embed;
10-12 16:03:59.492: W/dalvikvm(20569): VFY: unable to resolve static method 4683: Ljava/awt/Toolkit;.getDefaultToolkit ()Ljava/awt/Toolkit;
10-12 16:03:59.492: W/dalvikvm(20569): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/awt/Image;)
10-12 16:03:59.492: W/dalvikvm(20569): Unable to resolve superclass of Ljames/JpegEncoder; (657)
10-12 16:03:59.492: W/dalvikvm(20569): Link of class 'Ljames/JpegEncoder;' failed
```

So What am I missing here? Is there any thing I am doing wrong in linking the jar library. I am thinking that past methods of linking have become obselete. Am I right on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your library uses java.awt graphics, while android has its own. You should contact the edior of Steganography to tell him about the problem: they could do an adapter that works with the android ui classes.

Comment: so that means that the real problem is that I can't use the library which has java awt methods in it. I read on the SO on this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16632082/writableraster-in-android  that it is possible to implement the methods if they are not directly called in the android src and made in jar file. Is it true?

Comment: What you're saying is that you want to emulate awt under android. This is a pretty hard to evaluate task since it depends on how many classes and methods of awt are used in your jar. The best thing is to start by asking the conceptor of the jar about the impat: they will see through better that you can do